# Confusion about method overloading

Tags: java

I tried the following code, but don't understand the output:

```
Class A{
  public void print(Object o){
     System.out.println("Object");
  }
  public void print(String o){
     System.out.println("String");
  }  
  public static void main(String arr[]){
     A obj = new A();
     obj.print(null);
  }
}
```

**Output:** String

Why??

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method with the more specific argument type is chosen. String is more specific than Object.

Note that if you had another `print` method with, say, an `Integer` parameter, you would get a compilation error, since in that case the compiler would have no rule to decide whether to call `print(String)` or `print(Integer)`. The reason it works when you have `print(String)` and `print(Object)` is that String is a sub-class of Object, and therefore `print(String)` is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

If there's method overloading, the compiler search for the method from the most specific type to least specific type

From [JLS specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

> 15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method

So `String` is a more specific type compared to the `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

The *least* generic method among the *matching* methods will be selected by the compiler.
i.e, the compiler will first find out that both String and Object can be null. Then it selects the one which is at a lower level in the class hierarchy. (Object is at a higher level than String)